# Vim - Insert something between every letter

Tags: vim

In vim I have a line of text like this:

```
abcdef
```

Now I want to add an underscore or something else **between** every letter, so this would be the result:

```
a_b_c_d_e_f
```

The only way I know of doing this wold be to record a macro like this:

```
qqa_<esc>lq4@q
```

Is there a better, easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and a little more interactive way of doing this, all in normal mode.

With the cursor at the beginning of the line, press:

1. `i_<Esc>x` to insert and delete the separator character. (We do this for the side effect.)
2. `gp` to put the separator back.
3. `.`, hold it down until the job is done.

Unfortunately we can't use a count with `.` here, because it would just paste the separator 'count' times on the spot.

Comment: Something like this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: maybe add the 0 step:0. g0(or gg) "lead the cursor at the beginning of the line(file)"

Answer (score 5):

`:%s/\(\p\)\p\@=/\1_/g`

- The `:` starts a command.
- The `%` searches the whole document.
- The `\(\p\)` will match and capture a printable symbol.  You could replace `\p` with `\w` if you only wanted to match characters, for example.
- The `\p\@=` does a lookahead check to make sure that the matched (first) `\p` is followed by another `\p`. This second one, i.e., `\p\@=` does not form part of the match. This is important.
- In the replacement part, `\1` fills in the matched (first) `\p` value, and the `_` is a literal.
- The last flag, `g` is the standard *do them all* flag.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add `_` only between letters you can do it like this:

```
:%s/\a\zs\ze\a/_/g
```

Replace `\a` with some other pattern if you want more than ASCII letters.

To understand how this is supposed to work: `:help \a`, `:help \zs`, `:help \ze`.

Answer (score 2):

Use positive lookahead and substitute:

```
:%s/\(.\(.\)\@=\)/\1_/g
```

This will match any character followed by any character except `line break`.

Answer (score 0):

:%s/../&:/g

This will add ":" after every two characters, for the whole line.
The first two periods signify the number of characters to be skipped.
The "&" (from what I gathered) is interpreted by vim to identify what character is going to be added.
Simply indicate that character right after "&"
"/g" makes the change globally.
I haven't figured out how to exclude the end of the line though, with the result being that the characters inserted get tagged onto the end...so that something like:

"c400ad4db63b"

Becomes "c4:00:ad:4d:b6:3b:"